# How to check when UIImagePickerController changes type of camera?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an UIImagePickerController and want to know, when a user changes from the back to front camera (and back)?
Is it possible to get this information?

As second part.
After taking a picture UIImagePickerController shows a preview with (Retake and Use Photo Buttons). Is it possible to detect when this view is shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own camera overlay view to have total control over the camera switching and preview behavior. Without a custom camera overlay view, I think you're limited to just receiving the user's final choice in the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` callback.